# Duplex printing not working anymore (Epson BX535WD)

Tags: printing, 22.04, epson, duplex-printing

I recently updated from 20.04 to 22.04 and I realized that my printer can't print duplex anymore. It worked flawlessly with 20.04 and the default printer drivers, but since a recent update in 22.04 it doesn't anymore. I am quite sure that it worked before even in 22.04 (, but I am not 100% sure of that). When I now try to print double sided every other page is switched 180 degrees, as if the printer wanted to print double sided, but the page isn't pulled back into to printer. Any ideas why this is happening? Does anyone else have this problem or maybe even an solution? It's the same on two different 22.04 machines, but it still works with windows.
Best

Comment: Did you install proprietary Epson drivers?

Comment: No, I didn't. I never had to in 20.04 and as I wrote, I am quite sure it worked without them before.

Comment: They could install automatically and maybe didn't for 22.04. You can always install them.

Comment: Guess that's really worth a try. I would, however, prefer not to install additional drivers, if they aren't needed. Had bad experience with that in the past ;). Could anyone maybe confirm that Epson drivers are not installed automatically anymore?

Comment: You can easily check which driver is installed now. I always use Epson drivers.

Comment: Point your browser at the CUPS GUI  `http://localhost:631/printers`, select your printer and you can modify the printer to allow Duplex printing, if the printer has the appropriate hardware.

Comment: @waltinator: the problem is not that I can't select it. I select it and it just doesn't work anymore. Will check the proprietary drivers later.

Comment: The BX535WD is an IPP device. Vendor drivers are not required on 22.04 for either a network or USb connection.

Comment: Execute `avahi-browse -rt _ipp._tcp`. Automatic duplex provision is indicated by the`Duplex=` key in `txt=`.

Comment: Duplex printing with an IPP printer may be tested using the advice at https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSIPPUtilities#ipptool

Comment: Thanks @brian_p. I am also quite sure that it worked some days ago without vendor drivers. Could there maybe have been a recent update in this drivers since I haven't changed anything. Also there is no need to test it really since I know it worked and now it doesn't anymore, but its still selectable. And it's also still working in windows.

Comment: Is there a way to check the IPP for recent updates? What package is this included?

Comment: I also have the same issue with an HP P1606dn LaserJet printer. Worked perfectly in ubuntu 20.04 but failed in 22.04. I booted the ubuntu 22.04 LTS Live DVD and two-sided printing works works there. The HPLIP driver version is the same in both cases. Have no solution.

Comment: I opened I question at launchpad about this topic: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/702317